# Masking and averaging very large netcdf data with shapefiles in dask array: how to improve performance

Tags: python, performance, dask, python-xarray, netcdf

I am trying to work with 40 years of global-scale hourly precipitation data from ERA5-land. I want to mask the data using river catchment areas and then return the catchment average (average with in catchment) for every time step individually and save one netcdf for each catchment area. The following code works, but the total processing time is very slow.

First I make lists of all the data.

```
#create lists of ERA5 and catchment boundary files
ERA5_files = [os.path.join(dirpath,f) for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk("path_to_all_files") for f in filenames] # this is roughly 500 files. 

catchment_files = [os.path.join(dp, f) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk("path_to_shapefiles") for f in filenames if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == '.shp'] # This is roughly 5000 shapefiles
```

Then I read and combine the shapefiles into one geopandas dataframe `gdf`

```
gdfs = []
for f in catchment_files:
    gdf = gpd.read_file(f)
    gdfs.append(gdf)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat(gdfs))
# remove failures
gdf = gdf[gdf['gauge_id'].isin(passed)]
```

Then I write functions for processing the data

```
# write functions

#this is applied as a preprocessing step in open_mfdataset to speed up processing time and to switch the coordinate format to match the shapefiles.
def intconv(nc_stack):
    nc_stack['tp'] = nc_stack['tp']*100
    nc_stack.astype('uint16')

    # switch coords of era5 to -180
    lon_switch = nc_stack.assign_coords(lon=(((nc_stack.lon + 180) % 360) - 180)).sortby('lon')
    lon_switch = lon_switch.rio.set_spatial_dims("lon", "lat", inplace=True)
    lon_switch = lon_switch.rio.write_crs("EPSG:4326")

    return lon_switch

# this performs the masking procedure for an individual shapefile and writes the result to a netcdf. 
def nc_clip_return(nc_stack, gdf, a):
    shape = gdf[gdf.gauge_id == a]
    nc_stack = nc_stack.load()
    da_clip = nc_stack.rio.clip(
        shape.geometry
    )

    #save netcdf
    grid_mean = da_clip.mean(dim=["lon", "lat"],skipna=True)
    name = '/save_path/' + a + '_0200_era5.nc'
    grid_mean.to_netcdf(name, mode='w',format='NETCDF4_CLASSIC')
```

Then I open a dask client and read in a sub-sample of the data. This takes about 10 seconds and the resulting dataset is 3529 GiB (the total for all ncdf files would be about 7000).

```
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client()
client

start = time.time()
test = xr.open_mfdataset(ERA5_files[0:200], chunks={"time": 12}, parallel=True)
#test = xr.decode_cf(test)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Then i loop through the shapefiles, mask and average them and save as a netcdf file. My estimates suggest this will take months to run for all shapefiles. Any recommendations on how to speed up this process/optimize my code?

```
#loop through ids, average and save as netcdf.
for a in gdf.gauge_id.unique():
    start = time.time()
    test = test.rio.set_spatial_dims("lon", "lat", inplace=True)
    nc_clip_return(a = a, nc_stack = test, gdf = gdf) 
    
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
```

Comment: at this point the question is a bit abstract for ppl not working with ERA5-land data files. Can you add say 2 direct links to the input netcdf files you are using?

Comment: Isn't the computation IO bound due to the size of the input/output files?

Comment: *"10 seconds and the resulting dataset is 3529 GiB"* This is pretty huge to me (353 GiB/s). Even for a supercomputing node. Except maybe for a distributed computation on at least dozens (hundreds?) of nodes with a pretty good parallel file system. *"the total for all ncdf files would be about 7000"* Only twice bigger and this change 10 seconds to month? I find this confusing.

Comment: There are different solutions to this. But the obvious one is to average all the data and then clip it. Averaging should take hours at most, depending on how much data you have, which as said above is a little confusing. And from there the clipping should take minutes.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I am not "reading in the data" its lazy loading with dask. I then have to compute later to actually read it in

Comment: I wonder about the size of the original data (ERA5-land) and number of catchments, that you are trying to do... Most likely the resolution of ERA5-land is much poorer compared to the GIS layers of catchment area. If so, I suggest generating a mask of catchment areas on ERA5 grid... Afterwards, if you have merged dataset with mask (let's say in variable cmask) and ERA5 data, you can use xarray's groupby method on the dataset and generate easily time-series for different values in cmask variable...  I am using this kind of approach for different basins in my marine data.